# XCUITest : "Error loading video" when test is run from command line but works fine when run from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, xcuitest

I have a test for an app that picks a video form the Photos app.

```
    func selectVideo(name: String) {
        app.scrollViews.otherElements.images[name].tap()
        sleep(3)
    }
```

This test works fine when I run it from Xcode. App opens Photos, clicks on the video `app.scrollViews.otherElements.images[name].tap()` , and video is added.

But when I run it from the command line using command:

```
 test \
 -project "My App.xcodeproj" \
 -scheme MyAppUITests \
 -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 14'
```

When `app.scrollViews.otherElements.images[name].tap()` is done, I get the error in the screenshot.

I verified both Xcode and command line build is using the same Simulator by checkin it's id. I am using the same scheme and config too.

What could be the issue here?

[image]